# iOS - Background method to control all the views

Tags: ios, sockets, tcpsocket

I've an app with two viewController and a navigation controller.
It is an app with a tcp socket communication that call the server and receive a data according to the calling page.
I have a big problem in the secondViewController because the first connection don't close and when the server answers.. the first connection intercept the message.

The tcpSocket communication git: https://github.com/saturngod/simpleSocketChat

How can I close the first connection when I change the view or alternatively how can I create a masterView or background method that call to server and update the other views?

Thanks at all.

Comment: you have background thread which downloads data?

Comment: I use this: '#pragma mark - tcpSocketDelegate
-(void)receivedMessage:(NSString *)data'